# jquery add readmore for certain string

Tags: jquery

in a textblock if there appears '###', i wanna replace that by an image, everything afterwards should be hidden an on click, everything fades in, another image is added, the readmore image is hidden and on click of the readless image, text slidesup and the readmoreimage is visible again.

here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/TkPt6/7/

and everything works as it should with only one element, but there should be the possibility to add the ### to more than just one element, but there's a problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/TkPt6/6/

how to apply it to affect only the element that sould be affected?

and by the way, how to write a better code?

that's my js-code:

```
$('div.ce_text p').each(function() {
    if($(this).text().indexOf("###") > -1) {
        var readmore = '<p class="more">more</p>';
        var readmoreselector = 'p.more';
        var readless = '<p class="less">less</p>'
        var readlessselector = 'p.less';

        $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="more_content">');
        $(this).replaceWith(readmore);

        var hiddentext = $('div.more_content');
        $(hiddentext).append(readless);
        $(readmoreselector).click(function(){
            $(hiddentext).slideDown('slow');
            $(readmoreselector).css('display','none');
        })
        $(readlessselector).click(function(){
            $(hiddentext).slideUp('slow');
            $(readmoreselector).css('display','block');
        })            

    }
})
```

Comment: Consider using the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

Comment: but that's not for me but for editors and whenever they want, they just enter a '###' and it should work, as often as they enter it on a page an without adding classes or contains...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using you existing code I was able to amend it to work for the individual sections.

In addition you had a logical bug as well whereby the `less` was added per iteration to each section, which causes it to be added multiple times to any previous section already completed.

Using `on()` with delegation instead of just `click` you can move the click event bindings for `p.more` and `p.less` outside the each loop.

Updating the `click` events to use current scope to only effect the elements in relation to the current one.

```
$('div.ce_text p').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this); // cahced $(this);

    if ($(this).text().indexOf("###") > -1) {
        var readmore = '<p class="more">more</p>';
        var readmoreselector = 'p.more';
        var readless = '<p class="less">less</p>'
        var readlessselector = 'p.less';

        $this.siblings().last().after(readless); // fixed the issue of duplicated less
        $this.nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="more_content">');
        $this.replaceWith(readmore);
    }
})

// moved this outside the each as those can be bound using `on` with delegation
$('div.ce_text').on('click', 'p.more', function () {
    $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
})

// moved this outside the each as those can be bound using `on` with delegation    
$('div.ce_text').on('click', 'p.less', function () {
    $(this).parent().slideUp('slow');
    $(this).closest('div.ce_text').find('p.more').css('display', 'block');
})
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gUvBE/)

---

I'm sure there is many ways of doing this, I tried to use your existing code as much as possible though.

Comment: @sinini: No worries, I wasn't going to write all of it but got carried away. Was an interesting task. I learned a little more myself as well regarding some jQuery functions I haven't used yet. Thank you for the question +1ed it as well now. Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$(hiddentext).slideDown('slow');
```

To this:

```
$(this).next().slideDown('slow');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TkPt6/9/

Comment: Due to the general selector in the click events when assigning the css changes there is still issues when clicking the `more` option on the second section as it hides/shows also the `p.more` in the first section. The `.css` will also have to be updated to be in relation to the current clicked element.

Comment: Yup, but I wasn't going to write it all for him, he should be able to get what he needs from the example. Simply making the class change $(this) instead of on class will fix that.

Comment: Just using `this` in the css only works when clicking `p.more`. When clicking `p.less` though `this` is referring to the currently clicked `p.less` tag but the one the `display:block` css-change has to be applied to is the opposite `p.more` tag. It was a little more complex but I got it to work in the end. There was other issues as well with duplicate `less` tags and event bindings etc. Anyway, you are correct off course, no need to write it all :)

Comment: i've used the next, but because of the double appearence of the button in the first element, i removed it again, thanks anyway, i'm a 'she', by the way ;)